# I have used opencv for cloud detection but there is an error

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, detection

I have used openCV for cloud detection.. it can detect white clouds but when the clouds are being dark it's not detecting them.

so here my detection is > the white masking is for the clouds where the black is for the sky.

here what it look like:

this the original image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfW23.jpg)

this is the masked image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25FC4.jpg)

Here is the painted clouds which supposed to be masked in white color.. but here it is considered as sky and it's masked in black color. :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz4Hz.jpg)

it supposed to be all white since there is no sky it's just dark clouds..

how can I solve this problem? thanks

here is the code used:

```
def preprocess(image):
    """ Preprocess 'image' to help separate cloud and sky. """
    B, G, R = cv2.split(image) # extract the colour channels

    # construct a ratio between the blue and red channel sum and difference
    BR_sum  = B + R
    BR_diff = B - R
    # handle X/0 and 0/0 errors, and remove NaNs (not a number)
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        BR_ratio = BR_diff / BR_sum
        BR_ratio = np.nan_to_num(BR_ratio)

    # normalize to 0-255 range and convert to 8-bit unsigned integers
    return cv2.normalize(BR_ratio, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) \
              .astype(np.uint8)

def makebinary(imagepath, radiusMask = None):
    startTime = datetime.now()

    # read in the image and shrink for faster processing
    image   = cv2.imread(imagepath)
    scale   = 0.2
    smaller = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=scale, fy=scale)
    center  = [dim / 2 for dim in smaller.shape[:2]]

    preprocessed = preprocess(smaller.astype(float))

    if radiusMask:
        # apply a circular mask to get only the pixels of interest
        from cmask import cmask
        mask = cmask(index, scale * radiusMask, resized).astype(bool)
    else:
        mask = np.ones(preprocessed.shape).astype(bool)
    
    masked = preprocessed[mask]

    # use Otsu's method to separate clouds and sky
    threshold, result = cv2.threshold(masked, 0, 255,
                                      cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # invert the result so clouds are white (255) and sky is black (0)
    inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(result)
```

here is the cmask:

```
import numpy as np

def cmask(center, radius, image):
  c_y, c_x = center
  num_y, num_x = image.shape[:2]

  image_mask = np.ones((num_y, num_x))
  y, x = np.ogrid[-c_y:num_y-c_y, -c_x:num_x-c_x]
  # remove components outside the circle
  image_mask[(x*x + y*y) > radius*radius] = 0
  return(image_mask)
```

Comment: please use microsoft paint or snipping tool to draw out what you want to achieve. we saw input and output image. but we don't know what`s the output that you want it to be

Comment: @Dr Yuan Shenghai  , thank you , I have updated the post.